# What is the etiquette on number of questions asked?

Tags: discussion

While I have benefited from the knowledge of StackOverflow immeasurably for a good year now, I am a relatively recent questioner. After asking my first question and having an industry expert totally rewrite my code and point out where I was going wrong all in a matter of minutes I was blown away by the support this site offers. It currently being the summer holiday I am finding myself use StackOverflow more and more as a substitute for a lecturer. However, I am now worrying that my questions are reducing the quality of the content of StackOverflow since most of them are very specific to the problems that I am encountering and therefore both specific and basic.

Essentially my question for meta is should I self regulate and hold out longer, trying to use other sources much more than I'm currently doing before resorting to asking a question here? Or are basic questions in and of themselves worthy to have on the site?

Or to put that in other words, should a questioner aim not to have to ask a question, or should a questioner consider their question (and subsequent answers) to be a contribution to the site?

Comment: It's more about how *useful* the question is to other users. A basic question that would be useful to a large number of users that also isn't a duplicate or too broad or off topic is a very good question to ask.